# A simple question about replaceall and plotting

Tags: plotting, envelope

I was trying to replicate the picture produced on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolute) with the astroid emerging as the envelope of normals to the ellipse.  I ran into issues using the `ReplaceAll` command.  Here is my code:

```
ellipse[t_] = {Sin[t], 2 Cos[t]}
normal[a_, t_] = {Sin[a], 2 Cos[a]} + t*{-2 Sin[a], -Cos[a]}
Show[ParametricPlot[ellipse[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
PlotRange -> {-2.25, 2.25}], 
ParametricPlot[normal[a, t] /. a -> Range[0, 2 Pi, .1], {t, -2, 4}]]
```

Unfortunately, this produces the wrong picture.  The problem I think is how the `ReplaceAll` command is used.  I noted that

```
normal[a, t] /. a -> {1, 2}
```

produced

```
{{Sin[1] - 2 t Sin[1], 2 Cos[1] - t Cos[1]}, {Sin[2] - 2 t Sin[2], 2 Cos[2] - t Cos[2]}}
```

I really wanted the transpose of this, which fixed my problem:

```
Show[ParametricPlot[ellipse[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
PlotRange -> {-2.25, 2.25}], 
ParametricPlot[Transpose[normal[a, t] /. a -> Range[0, 2 Pi, .1]], {t, -2, 4}]]
```

I feel like there must be a different approach here.  Also, is it possible to have the lines (the normal lines in my case) be different colors from each other?

Comment: `Table[normal[a, t], {a, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}]`?

Comment: That seems to be an alternative work-around.  Indeed, it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To produce the behavior you want, you should make your function [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html):

```
Clear[normalListable]
normalListable[a_, t_] := {Sin[a], 2 Cos[a]} + t*{-2 Sin[a], -Cos[a]}
SetAttributes[normalListable, Listable]
```

Your function will now be automatically threaded over any lists in its input. Notice the difference:

```
normal[{2, 3}, t]
(* Out:
{{Sin[2] - 2 t Sin[2], Sin[3] - 2 t Sin[3]},
 {2 Cos[2] - t Cos[2], 2 Cos[3] - t Cos[3]}}
*)

normalListable[{2, 3}, t]
(* Out: 
{{Sin[2] - 2 t Sin[2], 2 Cos[2] - t Cos[2]}, 
 {Sin[3] - 2 t Sin[3], 2 Cos[3] - t Cos[3]}}
*)
```

You can check that you obtain the results you want from the `Listable` version of your function:

```
Transpose[normal[a, t] /. a -> Range[0, 2 Pi, .1]] == (* your version *)
 Table[normal[a, t], {a, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}] ==            (* my suggestion in comments *)
 normalListable[Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.1], t]               (* the listable function *)

(* Out: True *)
```

Answer (score 4):

I post this just to illustrate another way using [`FrenetSerretSystem`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrenetSerretSystem.html) which would be useful for plotting the evolute, e.g.

```
pt[u_] := Module[{t, fs},
  fs = FrenetSerretSystem[ellipse[t], t];
  {ellipse[u], ellipse[u] + (fs[[2, 2]]/fs[[1, 1]]) /. t -> u}]
```

Visualizing:

```
list = With[{res = pt /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.1], 
    p1 = ParametricPlot[ellipse[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]}, 
   Show[p1, Graphics[Line[res[[All, 2]]]], 
      Graphics[{Line[##], Red , PointSize[0.02], Point[##], Green, 
        Circle[#[[2]], Sqrt[(#[[2]] - #[[1]]).(#[[2]] - #[[1]])]]}], 
      PlotRange -> {{-7, 7}, {-7, 7}}] & /@ res];
```

You can use `ListAnimate` or export as a gif etc.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A quick way of visualizing the evolute of a curve as an envelope can be done by exploiting the fact that 1. `Cross[]` can be used to find the vector orthogonal to a two-component vector; and 2. `InfiniteLine[]` is now available in version 10:

```
ellipse[t_] := {Sin[t], 2 Cos[t]};
ParametricPlot[ellipse[t], {t, 0, 2 π}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, 
               Prolog -> {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Dashed, Opacity[1/2, Gray]],
                          Table[InfiniteLine[ellipse[t], Cross[ellipse'[t]]],
                                {t, 0, 2 π, π/30}]}]
```

[image: the evolute as an envelope]